# Aussprache Diminutivsuffix -chen als [ʒ⁠ən]

Tags: pronunciation

Die Verkleinerungs-Endsilbe *-chen* wird üblicherweise mit dem Ich-Laut [ç], einem Schwa [ə] und einem N [n] gesprochen: [çən]. So findet man diese Endsilbe auch in allen Aussprachewörterbüchern notiert, z.B.:

> Mädchen [ˈmɛːtçən]
>   Hündchen [ˈhʏntçən]

Ich habe hier absichtlich Beispiele gewählt, bei denen vor der Silbe *-chen* ein weiches D steht. Durch die Auslautverhärtung wird ein solches endständiges D wie ein hartes T ausgesprochen, und daran wird dann *-chen* angehängt. Zwischen [t] und [ç] meine ich auch noch eine Mini-Zäsur, zumindest aber eine scharfe Trennung, zu hören.

Bei solchen Wörtern höre ich aber oft, und zwar auffallend oft von Sprechern mit einer sonst ausgesprochen sauberen und akzentfreien hochdeutschen Aussprache, das:

> Mädchen [ˈmɛː⁠d͡ʒ⁠ən]
>   Hündchen [ˈhʏnd͡ʒən]

Die eigentlich zu zwei Silben gehörende Buchstabenfolge *-dch-* wird hier wie *dsch* in *Dsch*ungel oder *Dsch*ihad ausgesprochen. Das D wird also nicht verhärtet, stattdessen aber in die nächste Silbe gezogen und mit dem folgenden Laut verschmolzen. Gleichzeitig wird aus dem stimmlosen CH [ç] ein stimmhaftes [ʒ].

Belegen kann ich das z.B. mit [diesem Video](https://youtu.be/KNoU5KtbFAo?t=3m57s), in dem eine sonst ganz hervorragende Sprecherin ein sehr klares und exzellentes Hochdeutsch spricht. Bei 3:58 sagt sie aber nicht [ˈmɛːtçən], sondern [ˈmɛː⁠d͡ʒ⁠ən]. (Und das ausgerechnet in einem Video, in dem es um Aussprache geht.)

Allerdings habe ich das noch nie bei Wörtern gehört, die ohnehin auf einem harten T enden, bei denen also das [t] nicht erst durch eine Auslautverhärtung entsteht:

> Hütchen: immer [ˈhyːtçən], niemals [ˈhyːd͡ʒ⁠ən]

Meine Frage:

- **Was ist der Grund für die Aussprache von »Mädchen« und »Hündchen« mit [d͡ʒ]?**

Auch das interessiert mich:

- Können andere meine Wahrnehmung bestätigen, oder täusche ich mich hier?
- Ich habe das noch nie bei Menschen gehört, deren Aussprache deutlich von einem Dialekt gefärbt ist (zumindest nicht in Österreich), sondern nur von Schauspielern, Nachrichtensprechern und Politikern, also von Menschen, von denen ich annehmen kann, das sie eine Sprecher-Ausbildung absolviert haben. Warum wenden gerade solche Profi-Sprecher eine Aussprache an, die weder in einem Aussprache-Wörterbuch abgebildet ist, noch von gewöhnlichen Sprechern praktiziert wird?

Comment: Hm, auch nach mehrmaligem Anhören höre ich im verlinkten Video ganz klar ein stimmloses [ç], ohne eine Spur von stimmhafter Aussprache. Ich bin kein Phonetiker und höre vielleicht geringe Unterschiede nicht, aber ein [d͡ʒ] ist es für mich auf keinen Fall.

Comment: [**Hier**](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4dchen) wird die Kölsch-Aussprache _Mädsche_ genannt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zunächst zu dem Video, das du verlinkt hast: Bei aller Liebe kann ich dort nur den »üblichen« *ch*-Laut [ç] heraushören. Dennoch beantworte ich diese Frage, denn mir sind durchaus Leute bekannt, die *Mädchen* als [ˈmɛː⁠d͡ʒ⁠ən] aussprechen würden. Ich hatte auch, als ich die Frage gelesen habe, sofort eine regionale Färbung im Kopf, die das Video, das du verlinkt hast, aber leider nicht bestätigt oder aufweist.

In [Rheinhessen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheinhessen) – dem Gebiet südlich und westlich des Rheins in Rheinland-Pfalz, dessen Eckpunkte ungefähr die Städte Mainz, Bingen und Worms bilden – und womöglich auch in den angrenzenden Gebieten der Pfalz, des Nahetals und Hessens kann man tatsächlich das *ch* der Silbe *-chen* als [ʒ⁠] hören. Üblicherweise wird *-chen* zu *-sche* verkürzt und demnach in der Dialektniederschrift als *Mädsche* (oder *Mädscher)* dargestellt. Auch wenn Leute aus dieser Gegend Standarddeutsch sprechen, wirkt sich die lokale Färbung auf ihre Aussprache aus und der Diminutiv *-chen* wird mit dem [ʒ⁠]-Laut ausgesprochen.

Möglicherweise lässt sich dies diesen Freitag ab 20:15 Uhr in der Fernsehübertragung der Fastnachtssitzung *(Fassenachts-)* *Mainz bleibt Mainz, wie es singt und lacht* in der ARD feststellen – es besteht aber die Gefahr, dass alle Beiträge mehr im Halbdialekt oder deutlich eingefärbtem Deutsch sprechen und es daher nicht klar ist, ob sie [ʒ⁠] auch bei Standardaussprache verwenden würden.

Comment: Dafür krischese an Bembl. (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zum_Blauen_Bock)

Comment: Danke für die Antwort! ich habe mir schon gedacht, dass hier eine lokale Dialektfärbung durchschimmert. Vielleicht fällt mir das auch deswegen so auf, weil dort wo ich wohne (Umland von Wien) diese Färbung gänzlich unbekannt ist. Hier ist es entweder [ˈmɛːtçən] (oder eher [ˈmeːtçən]) mit einer sehr scharfen Trennung zwischen [t] und [ç] oder [ˈmɛː⁠d͡l̩] bzw. [ˈmeː⁠d͡l̩], in einigen Gegenden sogar [ˈmeː⁠l̩] (mit extra-langem e).

Comment: Mir fiel bei der Sprecherin auch auf, dass sie in diesen Videos auch ein anders Wort auf (für mich) ungewohnte Weise aussprach, nämlich das Wort »Wort«. Ich bin gewohnt: [vɔʁt] oder [vɔ͡ɐ̯t], wobei [ɔ͡ɐ̯] ganz klar als Diphthong ausgesprochen wird, mit betonten [ɔ], das zu einem unbetonten [ɐ]⁠ verschliffen wird. Bei der Sprecherin dieser Videos höre ich aber [ˈvɔɐt] oder vielleicht auch [ˈvɔɑt], wobei die beiden Vokale keinen Diphthong bilden, so dass sich das Wort fast schon wie ein Wort mit zwei Silben ("wo-at") anhört. Ich meine das bei norddeutschen Sprechern schon gehört zu haben.